# Removing a 'mystery' horizontal line from an <svg> element?

Tags: html, css, svg, zurb-foundation

I've added an styled svg border to a .  It renders as intended, except for a telltale horizontal line at the bottom edge of the svg element.

The svg source is

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 2600 131.1" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <path class="edge" style="opacity:1.00" d="M 2600,130.1 H 0 V 61 Z" />
    <path class="edge" style="opacity:0.50" d="M 2600,130.1 H 0 V 61 h 2600 z" />
    <path class="edge" style="opacity:0.25" d="M 0,130.1 H 2600 V 0 L 0,61 Z" />
</svg>
```

You can see the errant horizontal line here

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/hal924/pen/WzjbwG)

(it's across the bottom, in blue ... ).

I want the line gone.

I've been unable to style it away with (S)CSS so far.

I opened the svg in Inkscape to see if the line's in the source; at least in Inkscape, there's nothing there.

How do I remove that line?  CSS? SVG? other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I'll make it an answer instead of a comment:

You have `viewBox="0 0 2600 131.1"`, but all your paths start at 130.1. So there's your added pixel. Change it to `viewBox="0 0 2600 130.1"` (or change the paths to 131.1)

And to be more clear, it's the background from your .wrapper-element that is leaking through (try changing the background-color for proof), because your view box is slightly larger than your svg-content and because the svg is transparent where there is no content.

Comment: nice catch!  works perfectly.  wouldn't have found it myself -- at least for quite awhile :-/

Comment: how if i use svg in background?

Comment: @T-M What do you mean? The background color in op's case was similar to the colors in the SVG making gaps difficult to spot. So setting the html background to something bright would make it more obvious.

Comment: i use svg in css to make a background, with syntax background : url('../mysvg'), i already try edit viewbox in my file .svg but the mysterious line still show up. Any solution?

Comment: would you care to share the svg?